# Galois extension and subfield

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $E/F$ be a Galois extension and $Gal(E/F)\cong \Bbb Z/p^3\Bbb Z$.

Assume that there exists subfield $K$ of degree $p$ of $E$. (i.e, $[E:K]=p$)

Then, show that any proper subfield of $E$ is contained in $K$.

Here is my attempt:

Any proper subfield $M$ of $E$ has degree $p$ or $p^2$ or $p^3$.

For $[E:M]=p^3$, it's trivial.

For $[E:M]=p^2$, $Gal(E/M)\cong \Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z$ since Sylow $p$-subgroup of abelian group is unique.

Then, it contains $Gal(E/K)\cong\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$?

Also, for $[E:M]=p$, subgroup of $\Bbb Z/p^3\Bbb Z$ of order $p$ is unique as $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$?

Comment: You are on a good track in many ways, but it gets a bit muddy in the case $[E:M]=p^2$. Largely because $Gal(E/F)$ is its own Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: Have you covered Galois correspondence yet? If you have, then I would begin by listing all the subgroups of $Gal(E/F)$. Can you do that?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Hmm.... subgroup of cyclic group is cyclic, right? Then, $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is not cyclic? Also there are only $p^2-1$ elements that have order $p^2$, I guess...

Comment: Correct, Jinyong! All the possible subgroups of a cyclic group are themselves cyclic. Do you remember the result saying that a subgroup of a cyclic group is uniquely determined, if we know its order? This severely restricts the number of choices for the subgroup. In fact, there are only ___ non-trival ones? (you fill in the blank)

Comment: @DonAntonio It says that any nontrivial subgroup of $\Bbb Z/p^3\Bbb Z$ contains $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.... Little different from your words.

Comment: As usual, misreading: I could have sworn over my holy grandma's cousin's grave that I read $\;K/F\;$ and not $\;E/K\;$ ....thanks and deleting on its way.

Comment: In this case it may be better to think of that subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ inside $\Bbb{Z}/p^3\Bbb{Z}$ as the one being generated by the residue class of $p^2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Only nontrivial subgroup is $\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, and so galois group of any proper subfield of $E$ contains $Gal(E/K)$, so by Galois correspondence, statement is true! Thanks very much. I learned group theory last semester but little confused.... :(

Comment: Hey, but anyway: if our Galois group is the elementary abelian group $\;C_p\times C_p\times C_p\;$, then $\;K\;$ is isomorphic to one of the three factors, but there still are *other* factors of the same order that don't contain it...we'd still need to know more about the Galois group's structure.

Comment: @Don: It was given that $Gal(E/F)$ is $C_{p^3}$. Without that piece of extra information the claim would be incorrect (as you pointed out), but with this assumption in place, it is all plain sailing.

Comment: Well done, Jinyong. You could consider fleshing that argument out as an answer. You get more feedback that way.

Comment: Oh, dear: I really need to make a coffee break now. Did I miss that or was that added later? Anway, I'm off for a while. Thanks.

Comment: A silly question: Is $F$ the prime field? In the statement $F$ doesn't appear to be related to $E$ or $K$.

Comment: @PabloRotondo $F$ is just subfield of $E$ of degree $p^3$ and contained in $K, M$, too.